# Apache: redirect to non SSL page if TLS negotiation fails

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, tls, user-agent

How can I configure apache to redirect user to a non ssl page, if the TLS connection negotiation fails (i.e. they don't agree on a common SSL protocol with supported cipher)

It is using `mod_ssl`, apache : `2.4.6`

I understand that it doesn't even make connection when it fails to agree on something common to establish TLS connection, so serving response with header redirect isn't a straight option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. If a browser accepted a redirect from an unauthenticated (read: likely impostor) website after it failed to make a secure connection to the actual secure website, I'd be livid. That would be a pretty dire security flaw.

Comment: can we enable fallback to weaker cipher and weaker TLS protocol for just one URL pattern ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: Since the full URL is only known after the SSL handshake was done successfully it is not possible to have different protocol or ciphers depending on the URL pattern.

Comment: something like, try to do SSL handshake with level 1 set of protocols and ciphers, if fails try to do it with level 2 but once done with level 2, now when request goes through apache, see the level at which they agreed and if it is level 2 then only allow requests to certain URLS @Steffen

Comment: @JigarJoshi: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#strongurl

Comment: @Steffen thanks!, can I at application layer determine weather the connection has been made over which cipher, I was thinking to do something like land user to weaker cipher allowed page, so all can land in, make a call to another area with Javascript and check response, if it can get successful response that means this client is going to be able to talk to strong ciphers to have the app knowledge of it